# Инверсия осей(стандартных)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть стандартная ось "Horizontal" - со стандартными  значениями: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь когда я разворачиваю персонажа - т.е спрайт по оси x - данная ось в InputManeger не работает корректно, что бы это исправить
я хочу сделать примерно следующее:

```
if(fR.transform.rotation.x==-180)
        {

             //инвертировать ось управления (там на скриншоте есть галочка Invert) - т.е что то типа Axixs.Invert=true;
        }
else{Axixs.Invert=false;}
```

Но не знаю как обратится к данной оси? Ведь 
`float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` - дает только числовое значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Важно знать, что в рантайме ты не можешь изменять настройки. Ты не можешь внезапно вписать в `ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset`  данные. Ты максимум можешь их считать каким-либо способом. Поэтому, если ты хочешь инвертировать направление по оси, то достаточно умножить на `-1`. Так в игровой логике обычно и инвертируют направление по осям. В данном случае это будет так:

```
Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * -1.0f
```

Comment: Заведите в скрипте переменную и по ней ловите когда надо инвертировать)